# How can I have two separate labels on each coordinate using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use for loops to iterate a label with the coordinates of each point as well as a name. The coordinates work fine but all 6 names are iterating on each point. This is what I have so far.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.0, -0.15, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, -0.1]
y = [-0.1, -0.2, 0.0, 0.15, -0.06, 0.3]
titles = ["title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4", "title 5", "title 6"]

plt.plot(x, y, 'r*')
plt.axis([-0.35, 0.35, -0.35, 0.35])

for i, j in zip(x, y):
    plt.text(i, j+0.02, '({}, {})'.format(i, j))
    for name in titles:
        plt.text(i, j+0.04, name)

plt.axvline(x=0, c="black")
plt.axhline(y=0, c="black")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You are looping through each name inside the loop through each point. Maybe include ```titles``` in you ```zip``` like ```for i, j, name in zip(x, y, titles)```

Comment: `for t,i,j in zip(titles,x,y):...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing the right thing with zip, but now you can add `titles` also in it (also suggested in the comments above).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.0, -0.15, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, -0.1]
y = [-0.1, -0.2, 0.0, 0.15, -0.06, 0.3]
titles = ["title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4", "title 5", "title 6"]

plt.plot(x, y, 'r*')
plt.axis([-0.35, 0.35, -0.35, 0.35])

for i, j, name in zip(x, y, titles):
    plt.text(i, j+0.02, '({}, {})'.format(i, j))
    plt.text(i, j+0.04, name)

plt.axvline(x=0, c="black")
plt.axhline(y=0, c="black")
plt.show()
```

> Not sure to understand well what you want. Does this thing work for
> you ?